# How to create and save a Firefox profile using selenium with C# webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I want to create and save a firefox profile using C# selenium webdriver. And use the existing profile in selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a Firefox profile and then embed it to selenium code. You can use the default profile, but because of previous cashes and unnecessary addons, you'll maybe have 'Java Heap' error in first run. So the first step is:

***1. Creating new Firefox profile:***

1.1. Hold down the Windows Key and Press R on your keyboard and write `firefox.exe -p`

1.2. Click Create profile button on the opened windows and use wizard to create a new profile (In my case I created MyCreatedProfile)

[image]

2. **Your code**

   var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();

   FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("MyCreatedProfile");

   IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

Comment: I actually want create a profile programmatically and save it to use it later. And I want a C# solution. More important IwebDriver can't accept profile parameter.